# Can someone help me understand why my for loop is not working in Java (for a scrabble game)?

Tags: java, loops

Here is my attempt at writing a method to create a rack of seven letters. It seems as though my for loop is not worded correctly and thus not producing the desired results. Through many attempts I am either coming up with a variety of errors of the same letter is be given for all seven tiles.

```
public static Tile [] makeRack(Tile [] tileBag)
        throws FileNotFoundException
{
    // create a Tile array called rack that can hold 7 tiles
    Tile [] tiles = new Tile[7];

    // make a for loop that starts with int k=0 and repeats 7 times
    int x = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
   {
    char c = getLetter(x);
    int val = getValue(c);
    tiles[k] = new Tile(c,val);

   }
   return tiles;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to *get a different value for `x`* each loop. Anyway, "not working" is not a complete/suitable description. And, for Scrabble, which as a fixed set of tiles the 'correct' approach would be to use a [random] Shuffle to select the tiles.

Comment: It seems to be working for variable `k`. Is that what you want?

Comment: You generate your x letter only once outside the for loop

Answer (score 3):

You haven't included all your code, so I'm going to assume that `getLetter()` is a straightforward conversion from integer to char.

When you call `Math.random()` outside your loop, you get a (single) random number that you assign to `x`. From that point, `x` is not changed so you will get a rack of 7 of the same letter.

To fix this, move the initialisation of `x` inside the `for` loop. That way, you will call `Math.random()` 7 times instead of just once.

Comment: So I moved the Math.random( ) inside my for loop, but now it is saying: cannot find symbol - method getLetter(int).

Comment: @isuckatcoding: I'm not quite sure why moving that line would cause that error. Start with your original code in a state where you don't get errors, but you get 7 of the same letter. Then move the `int x` line into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is correct, but the key you use to generate Tile is only     generated once, this is why you get same values for 7 tiles. try to put the code that generate x inside of the loop.

```
int x;
for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++){
    x = = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    char c = getLetter(x);
    int val = getValue(c);
    tiles[k] = new Tile(c,val);
}
```